# How can I prevent a GitLab CI job from being retried manually?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a GitLab CI pipeline that has to be started manually. The pipeline pushes changes to its repository. This works fine.

I want that the pipeline cannot be run on a previous commit. But if someone clicks on the "retry" button of a pipeline, it will run on a previous commit.

Can I disable the retry of jobs, so that only a new pipeline on the latest commit can be run?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you don't want the pipeline to run on a previous commit?  Is your worry about rebuilding an artifact or something?  Perhaps there is a way to achieve your underlying goal in a different way.

Comment: The changes it pushes are maintaining a state (terraform). It might break things if it runs with a deprecated state. Maybe I should just pull in the latest commit at the beginning of the job to prevent it from working with an older commit.